# How to stop verification required when installing free apps

Tags: iphone

I've already done open the billing information , but the thing is "none" doesn't exists , there only "visa , master and Amex"

Comment: I believe adding a billing address _might_ be a workaround. It was a long time ago when I made my Apple ID. See [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no way around that to download apps, even free ones. You will have to provide the App Store with a debit/credit card on file. Don't ask me why, I don't work for Apple.

If you don't want to use your real card, you can use an old card (even a prepaid one), even if there's nothing on it. You just can't purchase any paid apps and the card must not be past it's expiration

There's an [official Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) on this, as found by IconDaemon.

Comment: This [Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) at Apple may help clear up some questions.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks. I incorporated that link into my answer.